# Which process is using 1099(jmx) port?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetty, jmx, intellij-14

I am deploying a jetty server in intellij but getting `12:36:12 AM Error running server: Address localhost:1099 is already in use`.

I checked for any process using this port:

```
$ lsof -w -n -i tcp:1099
$
```

But got nothing.

This is my intellij's deployment config file:

```
<component name="ProjectRunConfigurationManager">
  <configuration default="false" name="server" type="JettyConfiguration" factoryName="Local" APPLICATION_SERVER_NAME="Jetty 9.3.0.v20150612" ALTERNATIVE_JRE_ENABLED="false" ALTERNATIVE_JRE_PATH="">
    <option name="OPEN_IN_BROWSER_URL" value="http://localhost:8080/" />
    <option name="COMMON_VM_ARGUMENTS" value="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote= -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1099 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false" />
    <option name="UPDATING_POLICY" value="restart-server" />
    <deployment>
      <artifact name="supertext:war exploded">
        <settings DEPLOYMENT_METHOD="contexts">
          <option name="defaultContextRoot" value="false" />
        </settings>
      </artifact>
    </deployment>
    <server-settings>
      <data>
        <option name="configFiles">
          <list>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/alpn.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/annotations.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/apache-jsp.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/apache-jstl.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/cdi.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/client.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/continuation.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/debuglog.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/deploy.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/ext.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/fcgi.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/gzip.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/hawtio.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/home-base-warning.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/http.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/http2.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/http2c.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/https.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/infinispan.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/ipaccess.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/jaas.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/jamon.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/jaspi.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/jdbc-sessions.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/jminix.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/jmx-remote.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="active" value="true" />
              <option name="path" value="modules/jmx.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/jndi.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/jolokia.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/jsp.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/jstl.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/jvm.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/logging.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/lowresources.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/monitor.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/nosql.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/plus.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/proxy.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/quickstart.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/requestlog.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/resources.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/rewrite.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/security.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/server.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/servlet.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/servlets.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/setuid.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/spring.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/ssl.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/stats.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/webapp.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
            <JettyConfigFile>
              <option name="path" value="modules/websocket.mod" />
            </JettyConfigFile>
          </list>
        </option>
      </data>
    </server-settings>
    <predefined_log_file id="Jetty" enabled="true" />
    <extension name="coverage" enabled="false" merge="false" sample_coverage="true" runner="idea" />
    <ConfigurationWrapper VM_VAR="" RunnerId="Debug">
      <option name="USE_ENV_VARIABLES" value="true" />
      <STARTUP>
        <option name="USE_DEFAULT" value="true" />
        <option name="SCRIPT" value="" />
        <option name="VM_PARAMETERS" value="" />
        <option name="PROGRAM_PARAMETERS" value="" />
      </STARTUP>
      <SHUTDOWN>
        <option name="USE_DEFAULT" value="true" />
        <option name="SCRIPT" value="" />
        <option name="VM_PARAMETERS" value="" />
        <option name="PROGRAM_PARAMETERS" value="" />
      </SHUTDOWN>
    </ConfigurationWrapper>
    <method>
      <option name="BuildArtifacts" enabled="true">
        <artifact name="supertext:war exploded" />
        <artifact name="supertext:war exploded" />
      </option>
    </method>
  </configuration>
</component>
```

On deploying (running configuration in debug mode) following idea logs are generated:

```
2015-07-19 00:36:05,840 [38068479]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2015-07-19 00:36:06,720 [38069359]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar 
2015-07-19 00:36:09,344 [38071983]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -    COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 3507 ms: 0 min 3sec 
2015-07-19 00:36:09,874 [38072513]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar 
2015-07-19 00:36:10,057 [38072696]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2015-07-19 00:36:10,059 [38072698]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile /Users/aapa/Projects/supertext 
2015-07-19 00:36:12,242 [38074881]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -    COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 2195 ms: 0 min 2sec 
2015-07-19 00:36:12,658 [38075297]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar 
2015-07-19 00:38:14,299 [38196938]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
2015-07-19 00:38:14,302 [38196941]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
2015-07-19 00:46:09,710 [38672349]   INFO - ellij.concurrency.JobScheduler - 50 ms execution limit failed for: com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$1@53ed8465; elapsed time was 170ms 
2015-07-19 00:53:02,686 [39085325]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2015-07-19 00:53:03,027 [39085666]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar 
2015-07-19 00:53:04,410 [39087049]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -    COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 1727 ms: 0 min 1sec 
2015-07-19 00:53:04,799 [39087438]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar 
2015-07-19 00:53:04,949 [39087588]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2015-07-19 00:53:04,954 [39087593]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile /Users/aapa/Projects/supertext 
2015-07-19 00:53:06,518 [39089157]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -    COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 1573 ms: 0 min 1sec 
2015-07-19 00:53:06,907 [39089546]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar 
2015-07-19 00:55:58,284 [39260923]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2015-07-19 00:55:58,640 [39261279]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar 
2015-07-19 00:55:59,901 [39262540]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -    COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 1620 ms: 0 min 1sec 
2015-07-19 00:56:00,259 [39262898]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar 
2015-07-19 00:56:00,489 [39263128]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2015-07-19 00:56:00,492 [39263131]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile /Users/aapa/Projects/supertext 
2015-07-19 00:56:02,385 [39265024]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -    COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 1904 ms: 0 min 1sec 
2015-07-19 00:56:02,795 [39265434]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar 
2015-07-19 00:58:14,299 [39396938]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
2015-07-19 00:58:14,302 [39396941]   INFO - lij.tasks.impl.TaskManagerImpl - Updating issues cache (every 20 min) 
2015-07-19 00:58:54,073 [39436712]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2015-07-19 00:58:54,646 [39437285]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar 
2015-07-19 00:58:56,147 [39438786]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -    COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 2077 ms: 0 min 2sec 
2015-07-19 00:58:56,610 [39439249]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - BUILDER_PROCESS [stdout]: Build process started. Classpath: /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/jps-launcher.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_45.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/optimizedFileManager.jar:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA 14.app/Contents/lib/ecj-4.4.jar 
2015-07-19 00:58:56,650 [39439289]   INFO - ij.compiler.impl.CompileDriver - COMPILATION STARTED (BUILD PROCESS) 
2015-07-19 00:58:56,653 [39439292]   INFO - j.compiler.server.BuildManager - Using preloaded build process to compile /Users/aapa/Projects/supertext 
2015-07-19 00:58:58,407 [39441046]   INFO - lij.compiler.impl.CompilerUtil -    COMPILATION FINISHED (BUILD PROCESS); Errors: 0; warnings: 0 took 1772 ms: 0 min 1sec
```

Is there a way to check what might be causing it?

Comment: 1099 is not the JMX port, it is the RMI Registry port.

Comment: Why are *all* of the jetty modules listed in your `<server-settings>` element?  I would expect that to be an invalid configuration, as many of those modules are the same functionality but with different implementations.

Comment: Not sure I am first time using jetty, and as far as I can remember I used only the default configurations. Will check everything but first I have to solve this port using issue.

Answer (score 0):

try using this command :-

`netstat -tunlp ! grep 1099`

This will give you the pid of process which id using this 1099 port.

then try killing that process using PID of that process :-

`kill -9 PID`

PS:- PID is the pid of the process using 1099 port

Comment: This also giving no process with that port. The command which I mentioned in the question (`$ lsof -w -n -i tcp:1099`) is giving the result on my other laptop. So its not the case of any issue in these commands.

Comment: @knoxxs yeah, most probably